# What error "Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory), line : 1" in apache camel means?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, bindy

I try to implement transforming csv file using apache camel and bindy to a list of objects.

I tried to do it like here [http://www.mastertheintegration.com/camel/transforming-data-with-camel/transforming-csv-to-java-objects-using-camel.html](http://link)

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory), line : 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory), line : 1
```

Here are my classes:

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        final DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("model");
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("http4://127.0.0.1:18080/?filename=data2.csv").unmarshal(bindy).process(new CsvFileTransformService());
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

CsvFileTransformService.java

```
public class CsvFileTransformService implements Processor {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvFileTransformService.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = (ArrayList) exchange.getIn()
                .getBody();
        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {

                log.debug("key : " + key);
                CsvBean csvBean = (CsvBean) map.get(key);
                log.debug("csvBean : " + csvBean);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CsvBean.java

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class CsvBean implements Serializable {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String first;

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(String second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String second;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CsvBean{" +
                "first='" + first + '\'' +
                ", second='" + second + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does your CSV look like? How many columns does it have?

Comment: My csv file has 2 columns. It is simply: john, smith

Comment: Do you have any test classes? what happens if you send a csv line through direct to this route (instead of reading from http)

Comment: I do not have because in my case I want to use http.